# java simple association

Tags: java, associations

I am trying to add an association between Course class and Lecturer class, but I am getting an error.What am I doing wrong?

I am adding this piece of code into the Course class so that for each course a cordinator is assigned.

```
public void addCordinator(Lecturer newLecturer){
    this.lecturer.add(newLecturer);
}
```

Comment: What is the error? How is `lecturer` defined?

Comment: error: it can't find variable lecturer. Lecturer is a class with variables staffName,staffID.

Comment: @kamweshi, you need to show us the code for the whole Course class. Without the code, the error is impossible to identify, but with the code, it will be simple.

Comment: @kamweshi: Edit the original question with the full code. You can do that by clicking "edit" under the question tags.

Comment: I am bursting to ask: Is this homework?

Comment: @thkala: It's not homework.Just a book practice exercise I am trying to do on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure how your application looks like, but if you have one class called Course, and one called Lecturer and you want to make it possible for a course to have one or more lecturers, you can have a `arraylist<Lecturer>` inside the Course class. It would look something like this:

```
public Class Course{
   List<Lecturer> lecturerCollection= new ArrayList<Lecturer>();

//this method will be called with a lecturer object
public void       addCordinator(Lecturer newLecturer){
   lecturerCollection.add(newLecturer);
}
```

so you are now able to store lecturers for each corse, so if you have a Course object named course1, you can simply call `course1.addCordinator()` to add one or more lecturers to each course.
This is as much as I can help you with the current code you provided

Comment: Both  Lecturer and Student classes are in one package and there is a main class where main method is.

Comment: Supposing you are creating instances of Course and Lecturer from your main, you simply call methods to those objects from your main aswell. For example, if you create Course course1 = new Course, and Lecturer lecturer1 = new Lecturer, you can call course1.addCordinator(lecturer1). Do this from your main class

Comment: If you have your course+lecturer classes in a package, and you main in another package. Then you need to import the classes you need to be able to use them. So, if you have Main in a package called MainPackage, and Course and Lecturer is in a package called AnotherPackage, then in your main class (which is in package MainPackage) add import AnotherPackage.Lecturer import AnotherPackage.Course  on top of your main class